# MS SQL Transpose data to next column, max.transposed items = 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Below is my data format

```
Name           Tel           Email
John           25671234      abc@abc.com
Peter          98047766      aaa@kk.com
Peter          98047766      bbb@sc.com
Peter          98047766      ccc@kd.com
Peter          98047766      ddd@kk.com
Peter          98047766      eee@sc.com
Peter          98047766      fff@kd.com
Mary           33456789      987@dkh.com
```

Now I would like to change the formal as below. How would I do this using SQL Server?

```
Name           Tel           Email        Email1      EMAIL2      EMAIL3      EMAIL4     EMAIL5
John           25671234      abc@abc.com
Peter          98047766      aaa@kk.com   bbb@sc.com  ccc@kd.com  ccc@kd.com  ddd@kk.com eee@sc.com
Mary           33456789      987@dkh.com
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide a code snippet of your solution? What kind of output are you getting? What kind of difficulties are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the values and pivot.  I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select name, telephone,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then email end) as email_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then email end) as email_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then email end) as email_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name, telephone
```